# How to set different dates to different Users in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, date, users

I want to set different date for each user on my Windows 7,
is there any option? or third party software?

Want to change system date/time when particular user login windows.

thank you

Comment: This question makes no sense - is this for testing or something?

Comment: yes my friend I am testing some application, in which I need to change the date/time automatically when that particular user login windows.

Comment: They probably want to do something like (or exactly?) circumventing shareware expiry. In that case, a batch-file would be easiest and would avoid the need for a second user altogether. (A VM would also work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a batch file that uses the inbuilt command-line `time` and `date` commands to set the time to the time/date you want.

2) Setup Windows' Task Scheduler to run the batch file, with the Trigger set to when the user logs in, with "run with highest privileges" set in the task.

3) There is no 3. :)

Answer (score 1):

The system time is exactly that, the time of the system. There is no reason to have "user times" as the time should always be accurate and reflect the current time zone of the machine.

Comment: Thank you but, I need to change when logged in

Comment: What do you mean, when logged in? Their log on time, or update the time?

Comment: Yes  I am testing some applications, but I have to change the time each time time I check that application  that's why I want to create 2 users, one with correct date, another user with the changed date i.e the system time automatically changes  when the second user log in to windows.

Comment: @user252983 - This requires a custom application which is escalated to have Administrator permissions.

Comment: yes-Ramhound thank you, I want to know any 3rd party sw   or any batch file for this purpose.